# Difference between "$@" and "$*" when passing arguments to bash function

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, arguments, parameter-passing

I'm having hard time understanding difference between `$@` and `$*` when passing them to functions.

Here is example:

```
function a {
    echo "-$1-" "-$2-" "-$3-";
}

function b {
    a "$@"
}

function c {
    a "$*"
}
```

If calls:

```
$ b "hello world" "bye world" "xxx"
```

It prints:

```
-hello world- -bye world- -xxx-
```

If calls:

```
$ c "hello world" "bye world" "xxx"
```

It prints:

```
$ c "hello world" "bye world" "xxx"
-hello world bye world xxx- -- --
```

What happened? I can't understand difference and what went wrong.

Comment: "$@" is as many strings as there are arguments; "$*" is a single string.  There are many questions that cover this — I'll find one shortly.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler that's a good reading.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no difference between `$*` and `$@`. Both of them result in the list of arguments being glob-expanded and word-split, so you no longer have any idea about the original arguments. You hardly ever want this.

`"$*"` results in a single string, which is all of the arguments joined using the first character of `$IFS` as a separator (by default, a space). This is occasionally what you want.

`"$@"` results in one string per argument, neither word-split nor glob-expanded. This is usually what you want.